# bidding for a card game

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm tring to make a card game like Spades game for Android. In this game (different frım Spades) highest bidder will determine the trump. So during the bidding all players (north, west and east players are machine) have to bid at least once and if more than one player does not say "pass" he/she should bid again.

Three bids will be done by machine and one bid (south) will be done by player. For this code, if I use while loop, when south's turn comes the bid page doesn't come and player's turn ends with doing nothing. Thus, while loop never ends also (please see the code).

Could somebody give some advice?

```
 public void bidding () {
    turn = 0;
    boolean finish = false;
    maxbid = 0;

    while (!finish){
        if (turn == 0) {
            southBid();
            if (Npass == 1 && Spass == 1 && Wpass == 1 && Epass == 1) {
                finish = true;
            }
        } else if (turn == 1) {
            eastBid(); // machine says 8 or pass in this method.
            if (Npass == 1 && Spass == 1 && Wpass == 1 && Epass == 1) {
                finish = true;
            }
        } else if (turn == 2) {
            northBid(); // machine says 8 or pass in this method.
            if (Npass == 1 && Spass == 1 && Wpass == 1 && Epass == 1) {
                finish = true;
            }
        } else if (turn == 3) {
            westBid(); // machine says 8 or pass in this method.
            if (Npass == 1 && Spass == 1 && Wpass == 1 && Epass == 1) {
                finish = true;
            }
        }
        turn++;
        turn = turn % 4;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to implement some logic to the machines. Why will it bid or pass? That is not specified in the code.

Comment: Well, it will take time and I wrote if (bid<8) {bid =8} for now. They are in northBid(), eastBid() and westBid() methods in the code. At southBid() method a bidding page (which includes bid number buttons and pass button)  occurs (well if I do not use while loop I could see the bidding page).

Comment: Could you post one of your `bid()` methods? I'd like to know how `Npass`, `Spass`, `Wpass` and `Epass` are set.

Comment: I solved the problem myself. Thank you for your interests @pb772  and Micheal Dodd